# function pointer operations between 2 c source files causing compile-time errors

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, header-files

I am working on a small project to really help me understand c pointers/pointer functions a bit better. The application I am working on consists of 2 source (.c) files and 1 header (.h) file. The problem I am encountering is the following error when attempting to compile TurtleShell.c into a ".o" file:

```
[ahopkins@localhost TurtleShell]$ gcc -c TurtleShell.c -o TurtleShell.o
TurtleShell.c: In function ‘main’:
TurtleShell.c:12: error: ‘GetString’ undeclared (first use in this function)
TurtleShell.c:12: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
TurtleShell.c:12: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Normally, from my understanding, this would mean that I forgot to declare a function that is placed after main or that I forgot to include my header file as #include "GetString.h" and/or that the header file does not reside in the same directory (or /usr/local/include, /usr/local) as the source file utilizing it, however, the three files do reside in the same directory and the header file is declared.

One thing to note is that I am trying to access GetString() via a function pointer. I have used function pointers in the past within the same source file, but this is my first real foray into using multiple source files for an application that uses function pointers, so I made some assumptions in the process. The source code is as follows:

GetString.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
This function handles getting a string from the user by allocating each
character in the string to a char array. This array is guaranteed to
grow as large as it needs as well as trim itself down to only the needed
amount of memory to store the char array once the null terminator is
processed.
*/

int GetString(void)
{
    //Set initial array length reasonably. size_t is used due to it's ability
    //to allow an array to grow as large as it needs.
    size_t strLength = 32;
    char *stringPtr = malloc(strLength);
    if (stringPtr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory to hold char array. Exiting!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter some input: ");
    int c = EOF;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    //Checks the value of c (user character input) to see if RETURN or CTRL+C/Z was entered
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        //Adds the character entered into the next index of the char array
        stringPtr[i++] = (char) c;
        //Check if we have reached the end of the allocated memory for the char array
        if (i == strLength)
        {
            //multiply the current amount of memory allocated by 2.
            strLength *= 2;
            if ((stringPtr = realloc(stringPtr, strLength)) == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to expand memory to hold char array. Exiting!\n");
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    //End of input. This adds the null terminator to terminate the char array
    stringPtr[i] = '\0';
    //Check if we have any unused memory allocated for the array left. If so, we
    //shrink it down to be the size of the input including the null terminator
    if (sizeof(stringPtr) < strLength)
    {
        stringPtr = realloc(stringPtr, i);
    }
    printf("\n\nString value: %s\n\n\n", stringPtr);
    //Memory cleanup time
    free(stringPtr);
    stringPtr = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

TurtleShell.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "GetString.h"

int main(void)
{
    int running = 1;
    while(running)
    {
        //Create a function pointer for GetString() so we can manipulate the outputted string from GetString
        int (*GetStringPtr)(void);
        GetStringPtr = &GetString;
        char *string = malloc(GetStringPtr());
        free(string);
        string = NULL;
    }
}
```

GetString.h:

```c
#ifdef GETSTRING_H_INCLUDED
#define GETSTRING_H_INCLUDED
extern int GetString(void);
#endif
```

I know this has to do with the way I am trying to create the function pointer, as if I change TurtleShell.c to the following format it work as intended:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "GetString.h"

int main(void)
{
    int running = 1;
    while(running)
    {
        char *string = malloc(GetString());
        free(string);
        string = NULL;
    }
}
```

I am very green in C, as I have only been writing in it for about 3 weeks, so I may be missing something obvious. I have Googled this issue, but I found this to be particularly hard to word correctly in order to find relevant results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S - I am well aware that there are plenty of good GetString() type functions out there that I could probably use, however, this is for learning, so I am working on building my own functions as needed to increase the educational value of these exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `#ifdef` in Getstring.h should be `#ifndef`

Comment: Net result: "I forgot to include my header file"

Comment: Your awesome! I can;t believe it was a typo. I suppose I should be grateful that it wasn't something worse. Just out of curiosity, why did it work without the function pointer?

Comment: @AnthonyHopkins - compiling with `-Wall` flag will show that without function pointer, `GetString()` is assumed as what your header file would have defined it. But with function pointer, this assumption is not made.

Answer (score 1):

The following line makes no sense:
    char *string = malloc(GetString());

GetString() returns 0, 1, or 2.
That means you are allocating memory that is 0, 1 or 2 bytes long.

If you like to get the string you have read in GetString() use an argument, an pointer to char pointer.
You dont need function pointers at all in this case.

```
int GetString(char** string)
{
  size_t strLength = 32;
  *string = malloc(strLength);
  ...
}
```

Do not free string at the end of the function.
Do this in your main function.
You can get the string by passing an char* to he function like this:

```
char *string;
int ret = GetString(&string); // Get the address of 'string'
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this answer, however, the current code works as intended now. According to your answer, this behavior would be impossible. Am I missing something?

Comment: The variable (char pointer) 'string' in your main function will never point to the entered string. Instead it will point to uninitialized memory.

Comment: @AnthonyHopkins Which "behaviour"? With the help of Rémis answer, your code now compiles. But what it is supposed to do, still eludes me, too. Some of your comments in the code just don't make sense. A function pointer doesn't give you access to a function's local variables, but you comment in `main` sounds like this was your intention. Instead, you just allocate a new char array with a length according to the value returned by GetString, as Johannes explained. The function pointer is not even necessary to achieve that.

Comment: The most mystical thing is that you (besides never returning the pointer to the created string) even throw away the read string by freeing its memory before `GetString` is over. So even if something else in your program somehow got hold of the address of that string, it wouldn't be there anymore.

Comment: Intended behavior is to print the string that the user inputs to the terminal currently. Apparently I have this incorrect. once I get that, it's on to bigger and better things. I come from a Java background, so I assumed that this was a way to get local variables from one function into another. As I stated above, I was making some assumptions. I appreciate the clarification, as I know now what I need to do. The implementation was merely a learning experience, as I said before. I know I don't need it, but it's a good way to practice implementing pointer functions.

Comment: @AnthonyHopkins The purpose of a function pointer is to pass around the address of the *function itself*, so you can write generic code that, involves a function which (say) takes an `int` and returns a `double`, but the user can later supply the concrete function herself (for example comparison functions for sorting). But the only thing you can do with a function pointer is to *call that function*. Since you also tagged your question "c++", you might want to read about functors, which can achieve the same in a much cleaner way. But it seems that's not even what you wanted to do. ;-)

Comment: @Oguk: It Looks like I have some reading to do on this, but I do see what your saying. it was never intended to be used to pass data between functions, but to access functions, like a callback. I should not have made such a brash assumption.... Thanks again!